# Want to download GFS 0.25 data from Amazon Web Services

Tags: data-request, weather, python

Not sure if this question belongs on SO or here . Also maybe a trivial question where I am missing something . But I am trying to download GFS 0.25 x 0.25 data from Amazon Web Services (AWS). There is this link  - [AWS link](https://registry.opendata.aws/noaa-gfs-bdp-pds/)  but it does not give me a file that I want to download.

Here is some python code that I got from a notebook that downloads 0.5 x 0.5 resolution data

```
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.config import Config
client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
client.download_file('noaa-gfs-bdp-pds', 'gfs.20230809/12/atmos/gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p50.f000', 'gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p50.f000')
```

So this is the filename `gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p50.f000`   and there is this browse buccket - [browse bucket](https://noaa-gfs-warmstart-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) 
but it does not lead to me to the latest 2023 (today's file)

Can someone help ?

Comment: I see 20230809 in the path, maybe you need to change that? I think it is a good question for this site if download is working but the data is not what you expected.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Sure that is trivial and goes with the territory. What about the resolution though ? I am loooking for the 0.25 x 0.25 resolution.